# Can templates be nested in OctoberCMS?

Tags: twig, octobercms

I've started taking a look at October and while I'm able to build a default layout and conditionally include partials where needed. I'd rather nest layouts.

I.E. The `root` layout doesn't depend on any other layout, but the `nav` layout references the `root` layout.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
I'm looking at replacing *ExpressionEngine*. In EE I can have a `root` layout with my `html>head+body` tags. Then I could have a `nav` layout that adds in the navigation but references the `root` layout as ITS layout. So you end up with `root` that is referenced by `nav` or could be referenced by any `[page]` directly (if the nav isn't wanted/needed). Nested layouts just allow me to keep from conditionally including a partial in the `layout` or `page`. Just a cleaner markup in my opinion. Also, both the `root` and `nav` would have the `{% page %}` tag to indicate content placement.

So Ideally...

> Root Layout

```
<html>
<head>[common tags]</head>
<body>
    {% page %}
</body>
</html>
```

> Nav Layout

```
layout="root"
==
<nav>[markup]</nav>
{% page %}
```

So when a page references `root` there is no navigation displayed. However, when a page references `nav` `{% page %}` is injected into `nav` and the contents of `nav`+`{% page %}` are passed as the `{% page %}` content to `root`.

Hopefully, the additional info helps.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for with 'nesting layouts', could you explain it more in depth and maybe provide examples?

Comment: @LukeTowers See the question updates.

Answer (score 1):

Nested layouts aren't supported currently as such, but you can accomplish this with [placeholders](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-placeholder) and [partials](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-partial).

Here's an example of something that I currently use for my navigation.

**layouts/with-nav.htm:**

```
description = "Layout with nav"

[staticMenu nav]
code = "header-nav"
==
{# Setup the navigation menus #}
{% put headerNav %}
    {% set hNavOptions = {
        'submenus': true
    } %}
    {% partial "tmpl/nav-header" menu=nav options=hNavOptions %}
{% endput %}

{% partial "tmpl/header" %}

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="layout-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    {% page %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% partial "tmpl/footer" %}
```

**layouts/without-nav.htm:**

```
description = "Layout without nav"
==
{% partial "tmpl/header" %}

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="layout-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    {% page %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% partial "tmpl/footer" %}
```

**partials/tmpl/header.htm:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{% placeholder page_title default %}{{ this.page.title }}{% endplaceholder %} | {{ app_name }}</title>

        {% partial "meta/icons" %}
        {% partial "meta/seo" %}

        {% partial "meta/styles" %}
    </head>
    <body class="page-{{ this.page.url | slugify }} layout-{{ this.layout.id }}">
        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="home" class="header-area">
            {% placeholder headerNav default %}
                <!-- headerNav not defined in page layout. -->
            {% endplaceholder %}
        </header>
```